# What is the correct format for query string and path parameters?

Tags: rest, apiblueprint

I am using API blueprint to mock a set of real world endpoints and am having trouble combining path and query string parameters.

The real world endpoint has a query string parameter appearing 1st followed by a number of path parameters. I have tired loading this up in https://app.apiary.io but when I do it always moves the query string parameter to the end of the endpoint. What am I doing wrong?

```
FORMAT: 1A

# Milliman-Goals-Engine
Milliman-Goals-Engine is an API that allows consumers to view requests and responses from Milliman.

# Group Projections
Resources related to projections in the API

## Projection [/test/lts/objects{?startsWith}{/audit}{/projections}{/projectionType}]
Retreives projections by scenarioId and projection type

+ Parameters
    + startsWith: `1` (integer) - The scenario id of the projection
    + audit: `audit` (string)
    + projections: `projections` (string)
    + projectionType: `stochastic_request` (string) - The projection type to retrieve for the given scenarioId

### Retreive Scenario Projection [GET]
+ Response 200 (application/json)

        {"message":"Hello World!"}
```

Comment: The query string in an URI comes after the path part by definition. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I am asking how can a real world endpoint function with query string parameters before the path parameters (here's an article that explains the difference between the two. https://medium.com/@fullsour/when-should-you-use-path-variable-and-query-parameter-a346790e8a6d) and therefore how can I make api blueprint do the same thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "before"? That's simply not possible by URI syntax: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3

Comment: Ok maybe I am misreading what comes after the query string as path parameters, when they're not. I have an endpoint which looks like this that I can successfully hit. What could be going on? `/test/lts/objects?startsWith=1234/audit/projections/projectionType`

Comment: The query string may contain `/` characters, but this is technically all part of the query not of the path. This is not very commonly used though. Seems the tool assumes a query string consisting of key value pairs.

Comment: Ok I see I should have though of that. Thank you for your help. That makes a lot more sense now.